# Will the TP-Link TL-WR941ND wireless router work with Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04

Will the TL-WR941ND work with Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the router has nothing to do with your OS, except some rare cases (for example, Broadcom drivers in 10.04 LTS acts strange with the 40Mhz channel width configured in the router).

But if it helps you, I have exactly the same model, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why not. Generally the problems with Linux and networking are:

- on the other end (the network adapter - does it have drivers that work, etc.); and
- are almost exclusively regarding wireless devices.

Comment: Then I'm worried. The usb adapter is not from a well known brand, and the router is wireless.

Comment: What I mean to say is, a wireless router shouldn't be a problem *per se*. Perhaps there may be some issues with the USB adapter but not necessarily. We'd need to find out what chipset is in the USB adapter. Can you give me a model number for that part? Googling TL-WR941ND only turns up the router itself for me.

Comment: The USB adpter chipset is the Ralink RT2880U. The router chipset is the  Atheros AR9132-AC1E.